# Tinkerpop blueprints with Furnace

Tags: graph-databases, tinkerpop

Has anybody used Furnace(https://github.com/tinkerpop/furnace) with Tinkerpop blueprints? The library seems to have a number of good graph algorithms, but there are no examples on how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no official releases of Furnace and as such Furnace is highly experimental.  Furnace is part of the 2.x line of TinkerPop technology.  You would be better off looking at the TinkerPop 3.x line which takes the ideas in Furnace and rolls them into an improved computing model.  TinkerPop 3 will be in official release pretty soon.  You can read more about it here:

http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/current/#_the_graphcomputer_api